# Divide the MNIST dataset into 2 Classes

Tags: python-3.6

Basically I want to exclude 0 and 1 from the Dataset and want 2 classes i.e. Prime numbers 2,3,5,7 and Composite numbers 4,6,8,9.
I want train binary classifier i.e. Prime numbers and Composite numbers

Comment: Hi! Can you please share what you tried so far?

Comment: I am very new to this kind of stuff, so still figuring out the approach